# 'int' object is not callable :find the sum of elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to find the sum of elements in a list,where the elements are taken from the user,in a single line. But when i run the program it shows,`int` object is not callable.

**mycode:**

```
l=input().split()
print(l)
s=sum(l) 
n=len(l)
if(s%n!=0):
    print(-1)
```

When I run my program:

```
*error in line3*
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

and

```
'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi, is this the complete code? If not can you post the code with the lines causing the errors?

Comment: Does it show int not callable, or unsupported operand type(s)? Give a [mcve]. And note that `input().split()` will give you a list *of strings*.

Comment: please show your `list` print(l).

Comment: use l = [ int(x) for x in input().split()]

Comment: not working @rajenderkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [ int(x) for x in l.split()]
s=sum(l)
n=len(l)
if(s%n!=0):
    print(-1)
else:
    print(s)
```

Use type conversion

Comment: what was my mistake?

Comment: sum function should be invoked with list of integers only. You were passing list of string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the sample input that is throwing the error? I would wager that the list has both `int` and `str` types. Each element in the list needs to be coerced to integer, and if it cannot be, then the program needs to either exit with that error or only sum the elements of the list that can be coerced. This can be done with the `map` function. Example:

```
l=list(map(int, input()))

print(l)

s=sum(l)

n=len(l)

if(s%n!=0):

    print(-1)
```

(Python3)
This maps the list elements to type int.